# How to implement lua_lock/lua_unlock in luajit?

Tags: visual-c++, lua, luajit

I am reading this [lua thread tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial) and my lua code may be accessed by other threads at anytime and all I wan to do is to protect the luaState from corrupting.

I just searched luajit's source but found there is no lua_lock/lua_unlock in place. So is that possible to add such lock/unlock to luajit? If yes, how to?

BTW, I am using Visual C++ on Windows

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Perfectly reasonable question.  The implication of the linked tutorial is that Lua implementations provide lua_lock/lua_unlock hooks as empty macros, and that you can replace them in a platform-dependent way if you wish.  A quick grep through the source of lua5.3 and luajit2.0.4 (the versions I happen to have) shows that this is true for vanilla Lua but not for LuaJIT.

Answer (score 2):

LuaJIT doesn't provide support for `lua_lock/unlock`. You will have to manually control access to the `lua_State` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly stated in that tutorial, there *are* no "lua_lock/lua_unlock" functions, either in the regular Lua or LuaJIT distro. *You* are supposed to write them. The tutorial provides examples for Windows, but if you're not using Windows threading, you have to write them yourself.

Comment: Yes I know the tutorial has clear statements but I got my app crashed after I made the modification according to that tutorial(I am using lua 5.1 for test).

Comment: the callstack:> ntdll.dll!77bd224d() Unknown
  [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
  ntdll.dll!77bd215c() Unknown
  Test.exe!_LuaLock() C
  Test.exe!_lua_atpanic() C
  Test.exe!_luaL_newstate() C
  kernel32.dll!7753ed6c() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!77c0377b() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!77c0374e() Unknown